# Odoo call function

Tags: odoo-10, odoo, odoo-9

In new custom moudle I'm inherit odoo pos. Now I want call this function in my module.

```
orderline_remove: function(line){
    this.remove_orderline(line);
    this.numpad_state.reset();
    this.update_summary();
},
```

my custom module:

```
//OrderWidget
screens.OrderWidget.include({
    renderElement: function(){
        this._super();
        var self = this;

        //CALL HERE orderline_remove with line parameter
        //How get line parameter?


    }, 

});
```

Any solution?

Comment: Where are you defined *orderline_remove* function?

Comment: Refer this official doc of odoo: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/

Here you may get your answer.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo orderline_remove is odoo functio in point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js

Comment: do u got the answer@user_odoo

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var order = this.pos.get_order();
var lines = order.orderlines;
```

To get the order's lines. I hope this can be helpfull for you.